# Unable to create netlink socket — protocol not supported

Tags: perl

I'm running a software product called INetSim (http://www.inetsim.org/). It requires various Perl modules (including [IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPTables%3a%3aIPv4%3a%3aIPQueue)) that are already installed on my Ubuntu 12.04 system. However, I'm getting an error when running it. I'm not familiar with Perl but have attempted doing as much research as I can.

When I run the application after configuring it, I get the following error.

```
redirect - failed! Error: Unable to create netlink socket: Protocol not supported
at lib/INetSim/Redirect.pm line 1229.
```

Line 1229 of /INetSim/Redirect.pm is:

```
$ipq = new IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue(copy_mode => IPQ_COPY_PACKET, copy_range => 1500)
       or die IPTables::IPv4::IPQueue->errstr;
```

I'm assuming there is some type of issue with iptables and this function running but I'm not familiar enough with Perl or iptables to even begin how to figure this out. I've emailed the developers but am waiting for a response. Any ideas on what I can do to troubleshoot it?

According to a book I'm working out of that talks about INetSim, "When you enable redirection, INetSim creates all of the necessary iptables rules and redirects all connections going through the controller (my Linux box) at the appropriate service". I have done `sudo iptables -L` after running the program and it is empty.

Comment: The module passes `PF_INET` to `ipq_create_handle` as the protocol, but "valid values are `NFPROTO_IPV4` for IPv4 and `NFPROTO_IPV6`". You could try finding out the values of those constants for your system and pass the one you want using `protocol => ___` to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. After digging around, I found iNetSim doesn't work with Ubuntu 12.04 new kernel. After switching to the old 3.2 kernel, iNetSim works fine.

```
Linux test 3.2.0-53-generic #81-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 22 21:01:03 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```